# MAAS install iso download size?

Tags: 12.04, server, maas

Any idea what the size of the download might be the first time around right after installing MAAS? I'm experimenting at home with an Ubuntu MAAS install. It's a satellite link with about 1.5Gb's maximum download/upload. I'm running 12.04.2 LTS Server currently. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the stuff that maas-import-pxe-files gets, you can see the file sizes here:

http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral/releases/raring/release-20130429/

285M for i386 raring, for example.